# Does explicitly calling destructor result in Undefined Behavior here?

Tags: c++, destructor, undefined-behavior

In my opinion, the following code (from some C++ question) should lead to UB, but the it seems it is not. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class some{ public: ~some() { cout<<"some's destructor"<<endl; } };
int main() { some s; s.~some(); }
```

and the answer is:

```
some's destructor
some's destructor
```

I learned form c++ faq lite that we should not explicitly call destructor. I think after the explicitly call to the destructor, the object s should be deleted. The program automatically calls the destructor again when it's finished, it should be UB. However, I tried it on g++, and get the same result as the above answer.

Is it because the class is too simple (no new/delete involved)? Or it's not UB at all in this case?

Comment: The whole point of *undefined behavior* is that it is **undefined**. The fact that it "works" is only one of the infinite possibilities.

Comment: This destructor is too simple to have harm effects. I believe that calling the destructor is not a special case, but simply calling a method of the class. It has the special case of being called right before being deallocated (from delete or scope exit).

Comment: @ereOn: Thank you. I understand that it "works" in g++ doesn't mean it's not "undefined". However, the online answer (which might not be correct) is NOT UB, that's why I'm confused.

Comment: @EXP0: what is the "online answer" that you think might not be correct?  Could you provide a link to it?  Thanks.

Comment: Your usage of the destructors invokes UB (as it results in two calls to the destructors) but there are situations where you do need to invoke the destructors explicitly (When placement new is being used). Placement new is one of those edge cases that unless (or until) you need this advanced feature that is not really worth worrying about.

Comment: @TheJuice: Here is the link. Question 8. http://www.bestsamplequestions.com/technical-questions/cpp-sample-questions/cpp-sample-questions-2.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The behavior is undefined because the destructor is invoked twice for the same object:

- Once when you invoke it explicitly
- Once when the scope ends and the automatic variable is destroyed

Invoking the destructor on an object whose lifetime has ended results in undefined behavior per C++03 §12.4/6:

> the behavior is undefined if the destructor is invoked for an object whose lifetime has ended

An object's lifetime ends when its destructor is called per §3.8/1:

> The lifetime of an object of type `T` ends when:
>
> — if `T` is a class type with a non-trivial destructor (12.4), the destructor call starts, or
>
> — the storage which the object occupies is reused or released.

Note that this means if your class has a trivial destructor, the behavior is well-defined because the lifetime of an object of such a type does not end until its storage is released, which for automatic variables does not happen until the end of the function.  Of course, I don't know why you would explicitly invoke the destructor if it is trivial.

What is a trivial destructor?  §12.4/3 says:

> A destructor is trivial if it is an implicitly-declared destructor and if:
>
> — all of the direct base classes of its class have trivial destructors and
>
> — for all of the non-static data members of its class that are of class type (or array thereof), each such class has a trivial destructor.

As others have mentioned, one possible result of undefined behavior is your program appearing to continue running correctly; another possible result is your program crashing.  Anything can happen and there are no guarantees whatsoever.

Comment: Thank you. I don't have the standard document, and realized that I have to pay to get one. Would you mind providing the definition of "non-trivial destructor"? Is the one in the question a non-trivial destructor? Thanks.

Comment: @EXP0:  I added the definition of a trivial destructor for you.  The destructor in the question is not a trivial destructor.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis, what the paragraph says is not the same as you interpret.  The paragraph says calling the destructor of an object that has been deleted, and the question is asking for calling the destructor *as a normal method* before destroying it.  That's not the same thing.  Explicitly calling the destructor doesn't delete the object.  To explicitly delete the object you have to call `delete` operator on the instance (and it not being automatic) BTW, I have never heard about the possibility of calling the destructor explicitly, as it should be interpreted as the `~` operator.

Answer (score 6):

It's undefined behavior -- but as with any UB, one possibility is that it (more or less) appears to work, at least for some definition of work.

Essentially the only time you need (or want) to explicitly invoke a destructor is in conjunction with placement new (i.e., you use placement new to create an object at a specified location, and an explicit dtor invocation to destroy that object).

Comment: -1 But it isn't undefined. The language allows explicit calls in this way because it can be used and can be useful.

Comment: @Elemental: A explicit dtor invocation isn't UB in itself -- but destroying the same object twice most assuredly **is** UB. In fact, this is an example given in the standard (§12.4/14): "Once a destructor is invoked for an object, the object no longer exists; the behavior is undefined if the destructor is invoked for an object whose lifetime has ended (3.8). [Example: if the destructor for an automatic object is explicitly invoked, and the block is subsequently left in a manner that would ordinarily invoke implicit destruction of the object, the behavior is undefined. ]"

Answer (score 3):

From http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/12684

> Undefined behavior indicates that an implementation may behave unpredictably when a program reaches a certain state, which almost without exception is a result of a bug. Undefined behavior can be manifested as a run time crash, unstable and unreliable program state, or--in rare cases--it **may even pass unnoticed**.

In your case it doesn't crash because the destructor doesn't manipulate any field; actually, your class doesn't have any data members at all. If it did and in destructor's body you manipulated it in any way, you would likely get a run-time exception while calling destructor for the second time.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that deletion / deallocation and destructors are separate and independent constructs.  Much like new / allocation and constructors.  It is possible to do only one of the above without the other.

In the general case this scenario does lack usefulness and just lead to confusion with stack allocated values.  Off the top of my head I can't think of a good scenario where you would want to do this (although I'm sure there is potentially one).  However it is possible to think of contrived scenarios where this would be legal.

```
class StackPointer<T> {
  T* m_pData;
public:
  StackPointer(T* pData) :m_pData(pData) {}
  ~StackPointer() { 
    delete m_pData; 
    m_pData = NULL; 
  }
  StackPointer& operator=(T* pOther) {
    this->~StackPointer();
    m_pData = pOther;
    return this;
  }
};
```

Note: Please don't ever code a class this way.  Have an explicit Release method instead.

Comment: The code for `std::vector` (among others) will show a good use for explicit dtor invocation.

Comment: @Jerry, very true but not for stack values which *seems* to be the focus of the OP's question.

Comment: Yes, with that restriction it's a *lot* harder to come up with a reasonable scenario.

Answer (score 1):

It most likely works fine because the destructor does not reference any class member variables. If you tried to `delete` a variable within the destructor you would probably run into trouble when it is automatically called the second time.

Then again, with undefined behavior, who knows? :)

Answer (score 0):

What the main function does is reserving space on the stack, calling some's constructor, and at the end calling some's destructor. This always happens with a local variable, whatever code you put inside the function.
Your compiler won't detect that you manually called the destructor.

Anyway you should never manually call an object's destructor, except for objects created with placement-new.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if you want your code to be OK you simply need to call placement new and fill it back in before exiting.  The call to the destructor isn't the issue, it's the second call to the destructor made when you leave scope.

Answer (score 0):

Can you define the undefined behaviour you expect?  Undefined doesn't mean random (or catastrophic): the behaviour of a given program may be repeatable between invocations, it just means you can't RELY on any particular behaviour because it is undefined and there is no guarantee of what will happen.

Answer (score 0):

It is undefined behaviour. The undefined behaviour is the double destructor call and not with the destructor call itself. If you modify your example to:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class some{ public: ~some() { [INSERT ANY CODE HERE] } };
int main() { some s; s.~some(); }
```

where **[INSERT ANY CODE HERE]** can be replaced with any arbitrary code. The results have unpredictable side effects, which is why it is considered undefined.