# Program Crashes Upon Launch

Tags: c++, unity-game-engine, crash

When I launch my game, it seems to crash when I call the constructor. All it says is "a.exe has stopped working" and then I have to close the program. I've tried tracing the problem back through all my linked classes and headers but I can't see anything wrong. Maybe one of you can help me. Here are the involved classes:

```
#ifndef POKEMON_H_
#define POKEMON_H_

#include "MoveList.cpp"
#include "Elements.cpp"

    class Pokemon
    {
    protected:
        std::string name;
        double HP;
        vector<Move> potentialMoves;
        vector<Move> moves;
        int attack;
        int defense;
        int speed;
        int special;
        Elements element;
        std::string type; 
        char status; // (N)ormal, (B)urnt, (F)rozen, E - Paralyzed, (P)oisoned, (S)leep, (C)onfused
        // int ability;
        int ID;
        int level;
        double experience;
        bool isInAir;
        bool isInGround;
    public:
        Pokemon(double HP, int attack, int defense, int speed, int special, int elementNumber, std::string type, int ID, std::string name);
        ~Pokemon();
        virtual void setName(string x);
        virtual string getName();
        virtual void setHP(double x);
        virtual double getHP();
        virtual void setPotentialMoves(vector<Move> x);
        virtual vector<Move> getPotentialMoves();
        virtual Move& getPotentialMove(int x);
        virtual void setAttack(int x);
        virtual int getAttack();
        virtual void setDefense(int x);
        virtual int getDefense();
        virtual void setSpeed(int x);
        virtual int getSpeed();
        virtual void setSpecial(int x);
        virtual int getSpecial();
        virtual Elements& getElement();
        virtual string getType();
        virtual void setStatus(char x);
        virtual char getStatus();
        virtual int getID();
        virtual void setLevel(int x);
        virtual int getLevel();
        virtual void setExperience(double x);
        virtual double getExperience();
        virtual void setAir(bool x);
        virtual bool getAir();
        virtual void setGround(bool x);
        virtual bool getGround();
        virtual void setMove(const Move& move, int x);
        virtual Move& getMove(int x);
        virtual void attackMove(int moveNumber, Pokemon& opponent);
    };

        class Bulbasaur: public Pokemon
        {
        public:
            Bulbasaur(double HP, int attack, int defense, int speed, int special, string name);
            ~Bulbasaur();
        };

        class Ivysaur: public Pokemon
        {
        public:
            Ivysaur(double HP, int attack, int defense, int speed, int special, string name);
            ~Ivysaur();
        };

        class Venosaur: public Pokemon
        {
        public:
            Venosaur(double HP, int attack, int defense, int speed, int special, string name);
            ~Venosaur();
        };

        #endif

#include "Pokemon.h"
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

Pokemon::Pokemon(double HP, int attack, int defense, int speed, int special, int elementNumber, string type, int ID, string name): HP(HP), attack(attack),
                defense(defense), speed(speed), special(special), type(type), ID(ID), name(name), element(element)
                {
                    ElementsList tempList = ElementsList();
                    moves.push_back(Move());
                    moves.push_back(Move());
                    moves.push_back(Move());
                    moves.push_back(Move());
                    status = 'N';
                    level = 1;
                    experience = 0.0;
                    isInAir = false;
                    isInGround = false;
                    element = tempList.getElement(elementNumber);
                    tempList.~ElementsList();
                }

Pokemon::~Pokemon() {}

void Pokemon::setName(string x)
{
    this->name = x;
}

string Pokemon::getName()
{
    return this->name;
}

void Pokemon::setHP(double x)
{
    this->HP = x;
}

double Pokemon::getHP()
{
    return this->HP;
}

void Pokemon::setPotentialMoves(vector<Move> x)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++)
    {
        potentialMoves.push_back(x[i]);
    }
}

vector<Move> Pokemon::getPotentialMoves()
{
    return this->potentialMoves;
}

Move& Pokemon::getPotentialMove(int x)
{
    return this->potentialMoves[x];
}

void Pokemon::setAttack(int x)
{
    this->attack = x;
}

int Pokemon::getAttack()
{
    return this->attack;
}

void Pokemon::setDefense(int x)
{
    this->defense = x;
}

int Pokemon::getDefense()
{
    return this->defense;
}

void Pokemon::setSpeed(int x)
{
    this->speed = x;
}

int Pokemon::getSpeed()
{
    return this->speed;
}

void Pokemon::setSpecial(int x)
{
    this->special = x;
}

int Pokemon::getSpecial()
{
    return this->special;
}

Elements& Pokemon::getElement()
{
    return this->element;
}

string Pokemon::getType()
{
    return this->type;
}

void Pokemon::setStatus(char x)
{
    this->status = x;
}

char Pokemon::getStatus()
{
    return this->status;
}

int Pokemon::getID()
{
    return this->ID;
}

void Pokemon::setLevel(int x)
{
    this->level = x;
}

int Pokemon::getLevel()
{
    return this->level;
}

void Pokemon::setExperience(double x)
{
    this->experience = x;
}

double Pokemon::getExperience()
{
    return this->experience;
}

void Pokemon::setAir(bool x)
{
    this->isInAir = x;
}

bool Pokemon::getAir()
{
    return this->isInAir;
}

void Pokemon::setGround(bool x)
{
    this->isInGround = x;
}

bool Pokemon::getGround()
{
    return this->isInGround;
}

void Pokemon::setMove(const Move& move, int x)
{
    this->moves[x] = move;
}

Move& Pokemon::getMove(int x)
{
    return this->moves[x];
}

void Pokemon::attackMove(int moveNumber, Pokemon& opponent)
{
    Move currentMove = this->getMove(moveNumber);
    double damageDealt = opponent.getHP() - currentMove.getHPdiff();
    int attackDifference = opponent.getAttack() - currentMove.getattackDiff();
    int defenseDifference = opponent.getDefense() - currentMove.getdefenseDiff();
    int speedDifference = opponent.getSpeed() - currentMove.getspeedDiff();
    int specialDifference = opponent.getSpecial() - currentMove.getspecialDiff();
    char statusDifference = currentMove.getstatusDiff();
    bool isInAirDifference = currentMove.getisInAirDiff();
    bool isInGroundDifference = currentMove.getisInGroundDiff();
    opponent.setHP(damageDealt);
    opponent.setAttack(attackDifference);
    opponent.setDefense(defenseDifference);
    opponent.setSpeed(speedDifference);
    opponent.setSpecial(specialDifference);
    opponent.setStatus(statusDifference);
    this->setAir(isInAirDifference);
    this->setGround(isInGroundDifference);
}

Bulbasaur::Bulbasaur(double HP, int attack, int defense, int speed, int special, string name):
            Pokemon(HP, attack, defense, speed, special, 4, "Seed", 1, name)
            {
                BulbasaurMoveList temp = BulbasaurMoveList();
                this->setPotentialMoves(temp.getPotentialMoves());
                temp.~BulbasaurMoveList();
                vector<Move> temp2;
                for(int i = 0; i < this->getPotentialMoves().size(); i++)
                {
                    temp2.push_back(this->getPotentialMove(i));
                }
                vector<int> usedNums;
                srand(0);
                int i = 0;
                while(i < 4)
                {
                    int r = rand() % 4;
                    if(i == 0)
                    {
                        usedNums.push_back(r);
                    } else
                    {
                        for(int j = 0; j < usedNums.size(); j++)
                        {
                            if(usedNums[j] == r)
                            {
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                        usedNums.push_back(r);
                    } 
                    this->setMove(temp2[r], i);
                    i++;
                }
            }
```

And here is MoveList.cpp:

```
#include "MoveList.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

Move::Move(string name, string type, int PP, double HPdiff, int attackDiff, int defenseDiff, int speedDiff, int specialDiff,
        char statusDiff, bool isInAirDiff, bool isInGroundDiff): name(name), type(type), PP(PP), HPdiff(HPdiff), attackDiff(attackDiff),
    defenseDiff(defenseDiff), speedDiff(speedDiff), specialDiff(specialDiff), statusDiff(statusDiff), isInAirDiff(isInAirDiff),
    isInGroundDiff(isInGroundDiff) {}

Move::Move(): name(), type(), PP(), HPdiff(), attackDiff(), defenseDiff(), speedDiff(), specialDiff(), statusDiff(), isInAirDiff(),
            isInGroundDiff() {}

string Move::getName()
{
    return this->name;
}

string Move::getType()
{
    return this->type;
}

int Move::getPP()
{
    return this->PP;
}

double Move::getHPdiff()
{
    return this->HPdiff;
}

int Move::getattackDiff()
{
    return this->attackDiff;
}

int Move::getdefenseDiff()
{
    return this->defenseDiff;
}

int Move::getspeedDiff()
{
    return this->speedDiff;
}

int Move::getspecialDiff()
{
    return this->specialDiff;
}

char Move::getstatusDiff()
{
    return this->statusDiff;
}

bool Move::getisInAirDiff()
{
    return this->isInAirDiff;
}

bool Move::getisInGroundDiff()
{
    return this->isInGroundDiff;
}

MoveList::MoveList()
{
    masterList.push_back(Move("Pound", "NORMAL", 35, 8.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'N', false, false));
    masterList.push_back(Move("Karate Chop", "FIGHTING", 25, 10.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'N', false, false));
    masterList.push_back(Move("Double Slap", "NORMAL", 15, 3.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'N', false, false));
    masterList.push_back(Move("Comet Punch", "NORMAL", 15, 3.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'N', false, false));
    masterList.push_back(Move("Mega Punch", "NORMAL", 20, 16.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'N', false, false));
    masterList.push_back(Move("Pay Day", "NORMAL", 20, 8.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'N', false, false));
    masterList.push_back(Move("Fire Punch", "FIRE", 15, 15.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'B', false, false));
    masterList.push_back(Move("Ice Punch", "ICE", 15, 15.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'F', false, false));
    masterList.push_back(Move("Thunder Punch", "ELECTRIC", 15, 15.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'E', false, false));
    masterList.push_back(Move("Scratch", "NORMAL", 35, 8.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'N', false, false));
    masterList.push_back(Move("Vice Grip", "NORMAL", 30, 11.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'N', false, false));
    masterList.push_back(Move("Guillotine", "NORMAL", 5, 100.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'N', false, false));
    masterList.push_back(Move("Razor Wind", "NORMAL", 10, 20.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'N', false, false));
    masterList.push_back(Move("Swords Dance", "NORMAL", 20, 0.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'N', false, false));
    masterList.push_back(Move("Cut", "NORMAL", 30, 10.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'N', false, false));
    masterList.push_back(Move("Gust", "FLYING", 35, 8.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'N', false, false));
    masterList.push_back(Move("Wing Attack", "FLYING", 35, 12.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'N', false, false));
    masterList.push_back(Move("Whirlwind", "NORMAL", 20, 0.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'N', false, false));
    masterList.push_back(Move("Fly", "NORMAL", 15, 18.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'N', true, false));
    masterList.push_back(Move("Bind", "NORMAL", 20, 3.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'N', false, false));
}

MoveList::~MoveList() {}

vector<Move> MoveList::getList()
{
    return this->masterList;
}

BulbasaurMoveList::BulbasaurMoveList()
{
    MoveList y = MoveList();
    vector<Move> z = y.getList();
    potentialMoves.push_back(z[0]);
    potentialMoves.push_back(z[9]);
    potentialMoves.push_back(z[10]);
    potentialMoves.push_back(z[14]);
    y.~MoveList();
}

BulbasaurMoveList::~BulbasaurMoveList() {}

vector<Move> BulbasaurMoveList::getPotentialMoves()
{
    return potentialMoves;
}

IvysaurMoveList::IvysaurMoveList()
{
    MoveList y = MoveList();
    vector<Move> z = y.getList();
    potentialMoves.push_back(z[0]);
    potentialMoves.push_back(z[9]);
    potentialMoves.push_back(z[10]);
    potentialMoves.push_back(z[14]);
    y.~MoveList();
}

IvysaurMoveList::~IvysaurMoveList() {}

vector<Move> IvysaurMoveList::getPotentialMoves()
{
    return potentialMoves;
}

VenosaurMoveList::VenosaurMoveList()
{
    MoveList y = MoveList();
    vector<Move> z = y.getList();
    potentialMoves.push_back(z[0]);
    potentialMoves.push_back(z[9]);
    potentialMoves.push_back(z[10]);
    potentialMoves.push_back(z[14]);
    y.~MoveList();
}

VenosaurMoveList::~VenosaurMoveList() {}

vector<Move> VenosaurMoveList::getPotentialMoves()
{
    return potentialMoves;
}
```

Elements.cpp:

```
#include "Elements.h"
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Elements::Elements(string name): name(name) {}

Elements::Elements() {}

ElementsList::ElementsList()
{
    masterList.push_back(Elements("NORMAL"));
    masterList.push_back(Elements("FIRE"));
    masterList.push_back(Elements("WATER"));
    masterList.push_back(Elements("ELECTRIC"));
    masterList.push_back(Elements("GRASS"));
    masterList.push_back(Elements("ICE"));
    masterList.push_back(Elements("FIGHTING"));
    masterList.push_back(Elements("POISON"));
    masterList.push_back(Elements("GROUND"));
    masterList.push_back(Elements("FLYING"));
    masterList.push_back(Elements("PSYCHIC"));
    masterList.push_back(Elements("BUG"));
    masterList.push_back(Elements("ROCK"));
    masterList.push_back(Elements("GHOST"));
    masterList.push_back(Elements("DRAGON"));
}

ElementsList::~ElementsList() {}

Elements ElementsList::getElement(int x)
{
    return masterList[x];
}
```

And then the main function:

```
#include "Pokemon.cpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Battle Test 1: Bulbasaur vs. Ivysaur Same Level" << endl;
    cout << "test" << endl;
    try
    {
        Bulbasaur test1 = Bulbasaur(300.0, 20, 30, 10, 5, "Chris");
    } catch(exception& e)
    {
        cout << e.what() << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling all those destructors manually?

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for answerers to understand the problem. (Though in this case I would say that the best thing to do is simply place a breakpoint at the first line of the offending constructor and see what line is crashing. That should provide you enough direction to know how to fix the problem.)

Comment: I'm sorry, what is a breakpoint? I'm a newbie..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are calling the destructor manually on objects. It is very rare to need to do this (see [calling destructor explicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16720201/calling-destructor-explicitly)). When you call your destructor manually, it still gets called again when the object falls out of scope. Take for example:

```
BulbasaurMoveList::BulbasaurMoveList()
{
    MoveList y = MoveList();
    vector<Move> z = y.getList();
    potentialMoves.push_back(z[0]);
    potentialMoves.push_back(z[9]);
    potentialMoves.push_back(z[10]);
    potentialMoves.push_back(z[14]);
    y.~MoveList();
}
```

`y` gets destroyed twice, and this [**results in undefined behaviour**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291507/does-explicitly-calling-destructor-result-in-undefined-behavior-here):

> > Invoking the destructor on an object whose lifetime has ended results in undefined behavior per C++03 §12.4/6:
>
> the behavior is undefined if the destructor is invoked for an object whose lifetime has ended

Comment: You are awesome, thanks man. Learned something new today. This kind of stuff I would never know because its not in my book im using.